# $_POST Variable Detected in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am using 2 images in a form to sort out query results from the database. The form is submitted using the POST method. When i click on the first image, the query results have to be sorted in ascending order, and when i click on the second, the results have to be sorted in the descending order.
This is the code for the form:

```
 <form name="" action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="typep" value="price" />
   <input type="image"  name="sort"  value="asc"  src="images/asc-ar.png" />
   <input type="image"  name="sort"  value="desc" src="images/dsc-ar.png" />
 </form>
```

Now this is the code for checking if the `$_REQUEST['sort']` variable is set and therefore whether sorting is required or not.

```
if ($_REQUEST['sort'] != "")
{
    $sort  = $_REQUEST['sort'];
    $typep = $_REQUEST['typep'];
   //query to be executed depending on values of $sort and $typep
}
```

Firefox does detect the `$_REQUEST['typep']` variable but not the `$_REQUEST['sort']` one.
This works perfectly in Chrome though. When i test the site in Firefox, it doesn't detect the `$_REQUEST['sort']` variable and therefore the if condition evaluates to false and the search results don't get sorted.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incorrect.

Comment: Well why? I just did some research and found it to be apt.

Comment: The image input _does_ submit `.x`/`.y` coordinates, but it should also submit the actual value with the base name of the input.

Comment: okay. is there anything else you could think of as to how it isnt working?

Comment: Please properly indent your code, others need to read it. Additionally, for both browser, add the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to the question. Look in there, you normally see what the issue is if you do that.

Comment: You should mark an answer as accepted, if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently at some point in the HTML5 standard development somebody decided that the actual value of `input type="image"` is unimportant, and they decided to just not require browsers to submit it in any way: [link to specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set).

Unfortunately, it seems not only Firefox sticks strictly to the specification. [A comment to a bug submitted to the Firefox developers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583211#c1) states that this behavior is also observed in Opera and Internet Explorer.

So, you can test if the image has been clicked by inspecting the `.x`/`.y` coordinates submitted with the form, but you cannot determine which of the two images has been clicked, because you don't reliably receive its value across different browsers, and browsers that still pass the value will likely also follow the spec and drop it at some point in the future. You will need to name the two buttons differently.

Comment: Il try it out and let you know :)

Comment: How will i then get the value of sort, whether it is asc or desc ? I mean could you please write a line of code and tell me

Comment: I suspect that the reasoning is not that the value is unimportant, but that some browsers didn't send it and backwards compatibility was more important then more useful data being submitted in the future.

Comment: @Quentin I doubt that. HTML5 contains lots of functionality not supported by older browsers. Just because a feature was not supported by _all_ browsers, but by _many_ browsers nonetheless, does not warrant dropping that feature altogether, resulting in browsers that support it gradually dropping it to conform to the standard. It's like arguing that input placeholders should be dropped from the HTML5 standard, since before that standard many browsers did not support input placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Firefox will only send the coordinates of the click. If you want to use `input type="image"` you can use:

```
<input type="submit" name="sort" value="desc"><img src="..." /></input>
```

and

```
<input type="submit" name="sort" value="asc"><img src="..." /></input>
```

or you can use css to `input type="submit"`. `input type="image"` is equivalent to giving background image to button, so use that instead.

Comment: can you explain why ? i dont get user1707973's mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple input controls with same name in form , they will appears as array in PHP not as single value.

What does

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

or

```
var_dump($_REQUEST)
```

show?